# VSO build issue with WIX installer project

Tags: wix, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have an installer project (created through WixInstaller template) , it's in the solution where other projects are also present. Installer project unable to create the MSI installer due to build failure while the entire solution compiling in build server. Error is - 
**The project "XXXXXX" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".**
From Solution I am unable to configure it as "Any CPU" in Platform. It has few options
1. x86
2. New
3. Edit.

Tried so many ways but did not found "Release | ANY CPU" option.

PLATFORM Dialoge box -

[NO OPTION "ANY CPU" in installer project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Er2.png)

["ANY CPU Is coming for other project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSa1t.png)

Locally Installer project created the MSI (installer) file.

Thanks in advance for your help / suggestion.

Best Regards,
Deb

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue (a solution contains a window form app and WIX app), can you share a simple solution that can reproduce that issue on the OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

The Error is in the solution level.

In the configuration manager on the top of the dialog you can change the solution configuration.

Set "Active Solution Configuration" to Release and "Active solution platform" to Any CPU.

Then go to your Wix project as in the screenshot you have added and check the checkbox to build it.

Comment: Hi Arkady,
Thanks,

Comment: I did the above steps earlier, still can't see "Any CPU" option from the dropdown. Whereas other project have "Any CPU" option.

Comment: WIX installer project has only x86 option.

Comment: You dont need to change the project configuration, only for the solution. Can you post the full dialog of the configuration manager?

Comment: Uploaded the Full Solution Dialogue

Comment: Looks OK, the project configuration can stay x86. Maybe the solution file is not checked in the source control with this configuration. Open your solution in editor and check the configuration of this project. You can also compare the file from SC and the Local and find if there any differences.

Comment: The project configuration x86 is giving the problem while compiling the installer project in build server, it shows - The project "XXXX" is not selected for building in solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". I think it's required to selecr "ANY CPU" in configuration manager, tried to declare it in solution file through editing the .SLN file. still no luck.

Comment: Did you compared your local sln file against the SC?

Comment: Yes checked, problem is lying in "x86" / "ANY CPU"

Comment: I think - In VSO, Platform should be "ANY CPU" instead of "x86".

Comment: But did not get any option for WIX installer project in Platform (configuration)

Comment: Uploaded the Configuration images which shows with "x86" and "ANY CPU" options

Comment: If you want to add this configuration to the wix project you can select the new option in the drop down list or add it manually in the .wixproj file.

Comment: Error - The OutputPath property is not set for this project.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid Configuration/Platform combination.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='x86'

Comment: Please add your wixproj, the section of the configurations.

Comment: Hi Arkady, Lastly fixed the issue. Remove Installer project from Solution, cleaned the solution. Add WIX installer project. Add "<SuppressValidation>True</SuppressValidation>" in wixproj file, this will supress ICE validation. Update the configuration to Release mode and in ANY Platform. Run the project in build server, got succedded. Thanks a lot for your help. Best Regards, Deb

Comment: Great to hear, this is mean your solution file was not the same in the SC.

Comment: Compared yesterday, it was same. Don't know why it failed yesterday. Thanks.